# How to set a bash script to run at startup?

Tags: startup, autostart

How can I set my script to run after reboot once the desktop loads?

I tried `sudo update-rc.d myscript defaults` but it doesn't seem to be working...

I don't know how to use cron is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this for a non-`root` user, the easy way is `cron` with an entry like:

```
 @reboot /path/to/myscript
```

Note that the `PATH` and other components of the environment are extremely stripped down within the `cron` environment, so try and specify full paths to everything.

The syntax is slightly different for `root`:

```
 @reboot run_as_user /path/to/myscript
```

Where `run_as_user` represents which user to run the script as.

Comment: I already tried, but it doesn't work. If I type in `crontab -l`, it says that the commands are active, but they don't execute at startup...

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it, but if it isn't working maybe you have a problem with `cron`? I'd try and diagnose that as a separate question, but it's a better fit on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) since this is an OS-related question more than a programming one.

Comment: Ok I'll try thanks